# HLSL isn't interpolating values?

Tags: directx, shader, hlsl, interpolation

I have a very simple VS and PS that are supposed to draw a screen-sized quad on the screen. However, my tests to colorize based on texture coordinate are showing a solid color across the entire rect (screen) instead of interpolated fading colors along the x and y direction. Here is my shader code:

```
struct FRAGMENT {float4 position:SV_POSITION; float3 tex_coord:TEXCOORD0;};

FRAGMENT vs_main(uint vertex_id : SV_VertexID) {
    FRAGMENT OUT;
    OUT.tex_coord = float3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    if(vertex_id == 1) OUT.tex_coord.x = 1.0f;
    else if(vertex_id == 2) OUT.tex_coord.y = 1.0f;
    else if(vertex_id == 3) OUT.tex_coord.xy = float2(1.0f, 1.0f);
    OUT.position = float4(OUT.tex_coord.x * 2.0f - 1.0f, OUT.tex_coord.y * 2.0f - 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    return OUT;
}

float4 ps_main(FRAGMENT IN) : SV_TARGET {
    return float4(IN.tex_coord, 1.0f);
}
```

The quad draws just fine, and I can color it manually, but the value for IN.tex_coord is solid across the entire screen. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: Do you draw the quad with indexed vertices or without? Only with indexed vertices the ID is the vertexID, otherwise it is a counter of drawn vertices at the current moment (source http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205118%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't use indexed vertices, I just Draw(4,0) which sends 4 vertices through the pipeline using triangle strip topology. It should ID the vertices with the triangle strip

Comment: As I understand the doc `For each draw call, the vertex id is incremented by 1.` in the first frame the id's should be right, but then it counts higher and higher, because it isn't resetted. I would suppose to modify your if with a modulo or draw an indexed quad.

Comment: Try to set the w-component of `OUT.position` to `1`.